# Why RepeatableRead isolation level not working with EF Core when trying to avoid inserting entities with the same key into the database?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, entity-framework-core, isolation-level

I'm trying to avoid multiple row insertion with the same `Identifier` field value into the database. Here is the code:

```
public async Task InsertTransaction(Transaction transaction)
    {
        await using var dbTransaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
                 
        var existing = await _dbContext.Set<Transaction>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Identifier == transaction.Identifier);

        if (existing != null) {
            return;
        }

        _dbContext.Set<Transaction>().Add(transaction);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        await dbTransaction.CommitAsync();
        return;
    }
```

I'm assuming that `RepeatableRead` isolation level should be enough here, as it should lock for reading queries with search criteria containing `Identifier` and all requests after first one stepping into transaction will wait for it to finish.
However when running concurrent tests I'm getting multiple rows inserted with the same `Identifier` and things work properly only after changing transaction isolation level to `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming that RepeatableRead isolation level should be enough here

No.  REPEATABLE READ doesn't use [key range locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#key_range) for non-existent data.  SERIALIZABLE is the only isolation level that does.  Although SERIALIZABLE will take Shared (S) range locks, and so after multiple sessions hold the same S lock, the conflicting inserts will create a deadlock, instead of blocking the second session at the SELECT query.

> I'm getting multiple rows inserted with the same Identifier

In addition to an insert-if-not-exists transaction, you should *also* have a unique index on `Identifier` to *prevent* duplicates.

In SQL Server the lock hints to use are `updlock,holdlock`, which force restrictive update (U) locks, and key range locking.  So something like:

```
public bool Exists<TEntity>(int Id) where TEntity: class
{
    var et = this.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
    return this.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw($"select * from [{et.GetSchema()??"dbo"}].[{et.GetTableName()}] with(updlock,holdlock) where Id = @Id",new SqlParameter("@Id",Id)).Any();
}
```

You still need a transaction or the U locks will be released immediately, but the transaction can be at the default READ COMMITTED isolation level.

Comment: Thank you for response, and is there any way for avoiding deadlocks and implementing this insert-if-not-exists logic properly (using entity framework)
Perhaps there is an option to do that by using `hints`? if so please let me know, as I've implemented basic Hints support for EF Core

Comment: Thanks once again, funny thing is that I've been trying to play with that hints even before writing the question but my solution didn't work because actually as found out hints haven't been applying to the resulting EF Core query. And do you think that `rowlock, holdlock` combination would be better choice here? And final question - how reliable hints approach is? As far as I know by adding hints we just suggest SqlServer what locks to have but it might go with other locking strategy in some cases

Comment: Lock hints are not optional, although they don’t control what index is used.  If the lookup is by the primary key it should be fine, but if there are multiple indexes that could be used, you might want to hint the index as well.